# Getting error while executing makeinfo on cygwin

Tags: perl, cygwin, texinfo

While executing makeinfo on cygwin I am getting the following errors. I am using the perl version 5.32.1

23:16 Harshal:~> makeinfo
Can't locate if.pm in @INC (you may need to install the if module) (@INC contains: /usr/lib/texinfo /usr/share/texinfo/lib/Text-Unidecode/lib /usr/share/texinfo/lib/Unicode-EastAsianWidth/lib /usr/share/texinfo/lib/libintl-perl/lib /usr/share/texinfo /usr/share/texinfo /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.32/x86_64-cygwin-threads /usr/local/share/perl5/site_perl/5.32 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.32/x86_64-cygwin-threads /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/5.32 /usr/lib/perl5/5.32/x86_64-cygwin-threads /usr/share/perl5/5.32) at /usr/share/texinfo/Texinfo/Structuring.pm line 27.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/texinfo/Texinfo/Structuring.pm line 27.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/texinfo/Texinfo/Convert/Converter.pm line 32.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/texinfo/Texinfo/Convert/Converter.pm line 32.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/bin/makeinfo line 99.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/bin/makeinfo line 99.

If someone can provide some pointer on how to resolve this issue would be helpful

I tried updating the perl version. I tried commetting out the code on line num 27 in structuring.pm didn;t workout. I am not from software background but i need the above thing for some RISCV based toolchain update.

Any help woudl be really appreciated .

Comment: Please inspect your [environment variables](https://perlmaven.com/how-to-change-inc-to-find-perl-modules-in-non-standard-locations), there is a possibility that variables point to wrong location for module files.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Something's wrong with your system. This is a file included in the [perl-5.32.1-2 package](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86_64%2Fperl%2Fperl-5.32.1-2&grep=%2Fif%5C.pm%24). It should be found at

```
/usr/share/perl5/5.32/if.pm
```

Try reinstalling the `perl` package. If the file isn't missing, something's wrong with the permissions.